# Cloth texture not rendering properly when animating

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, texturing, armature, cloth-simulation

I have created a character, rigged it and added clothes. These clothes are rigged to the armature and the skirt has a cloth modifier added at the end so it moves properly.

The problem is that in the viewport the texture looks fine but when I render the texture is all messed up. This only happens in the frames where the cloth and the rig starts to move. All the textures are mapped form the UV of the skirt. I don´t really know why this only happens on the final render but not in the preview. 
[image: viewport]

[image: render]

[image: material]

[image: load order]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your "Viewport" and "Render" subdivisions are set differently. Depending on how you're rendering, that can make a *huge* difference at values that low (0-3 really). It may also be affecting baked cloth simulations.

I recommend setting them to the same value. Possibly also bumping it up to 3.